# A simple Symmetric class using args in void main (String[] args)

Tags: java

In a class called Symmetric with a main() method. The main() method accepts an arbitrary number of command line arguments including none. It determines if the command line arguments are symmetric: first equal to last, second equal to second to last, and so forth. If the arguments are symmetric, the expression

```
All args symmetric
```

is printed. If an asymmetry is found a message like

```
Not symmetric at arg 1:b and 2:a
```

is printed where the numbers correspond to the argument index (starting form 0) and the letters correspond to the actual arguments.
Example runs are below.

```
> javac Symmetric.java 
> java Symmetric
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric a
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric a a
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric a b
Not symmetric at arg 0:a and 1:b
> java Symmetric a b a
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric a b a c
Not symmetric at arg 0:a and 3:c
> java Symmetric a b a a
Not symmetric at arg 1:b and 2:a
> java Symmetric c a b a b a c
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric c a b d b a c
All args symmetric
> java Symmetric c a b d r a c
Not symmetric at arg 2:b and 4:r
```

here are my codes:

```
public class Symmetric{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
     int i =0;
     int j=args.length-1;

     if (args[i].equals(args[j])==false){
       System.out.println ("Not symmetric at arg "+i+":"+args[i]+" and "+j+":"+args[j]);
     }
     while(args[i].equals(args[j]) && i<=j) {
       if (i==j || i==j-1 || i==j-2){     
         System.out.println ("All args symmetric");
        // System.exit(1);
       }
       i++;
       j--;
     }         
  }
}
```

I can pass all the examples above except the first two. when I enter

```
java Symmetric
java Symmetric a
```

I always get ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. How can i deal with the situation that no value is passed in or just one value is passed in?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this question with python and c++?  Or just java? I'll fix it for you.  I suppose you could re-add the tags, but if you do, please explain why.  Edit: ninja'd by merlin :)

Comment: @jedwards, I already removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-order your code a little bit so you always check indices before using them, then you can pass those cases.

```
public class Symmetric{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i =0;
        int j=args.length-1;

        boolean sym =true;
        while(i < j) {
            if (!args[i].equals(args[j])){
                System.out.println("Not symmetric at arg "+i+":"+args[i]+" and "+j+":"+args[j]);
                sym = false;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        if (sym) System.out.println ("All args symmetric");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do parameter checking first:

```
public class Symmetric{
  public static void main (String[] args) {

     if(args.length == 0) {
         return;
     }

     ...
```